# IntelliJ IDEA схлопывает директории проекта с БД

Tags: intellij-idea

Клонировал БД с репозитория, в проект с IDEA, когда проект грузится, все ок, корневая папка помечается, все директории с процедурами отображаются, но спустя секунд 5 после запуска, idea схлопывает все

В чем может быть проблема в такой ситуации? Invalidate caches чистил

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]